# how to find out the name of the server on which the files are hosted on?

Tags: linux, command-line, nfs

I've tried numerous thing such as `uname -a`, `env`, findsmb, amongst other things  but that will only give the hostname which is not the server where the files are hosted... I get that there is nfs server somewhere that is sharing the files to the host that I am connected to, but, I am not sure which command to even determine what its name is or even its ip.

I'll be blunt about this is for a lab that I was unfortunately sick for and still waiting for an email response from my lab instructor with the same question, but, with the lab being due in a few hours I am going say this individual isn't going to respond in time, but, I digress. Ultimately, a gentle push in the right direction would be preferred as suppose to a direct answer (if possible).

Comment: Have you considered **mount** or **df**?

Comment: try this: `sudo df`. If you can `cd` to a directory that has a mount from this remote server, you can use `sudo df .` to find out where the directory is being mounted from.

Comment: To those who think this question is unclear would you mind specifying what you think is unclear and I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine where a file is hosted this is what I do:

```
cd /path/to/folder
df -k .
```

The host name where the file is sourced from is at the beginning of second line.

Comment: I got the same output as I did when I just used df.

Comment: We'll, my answer does tell you the host where the files truly reside. I'm not sure why this is not what you're looking for. Maybe some example of what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, but the comment was deleted but I had mentioned that I was getting some denied permissions and wasn't sure if the output was what you were expecting me to see. Nonetheless this is correct and I have marked it so.